# Retrieving random number after a jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get a single random number after a jQuery click that is within another jQuery click; but what I get is a lot of random numbers.

```
$("#onePl").on("click",function(){
       $("#myId").click(function(){
          var ran=Math.random();
          console.log(ran);// lot of random numbers in sequence
             })
  })
```

Comment: Your code gives exactly one number

Comment: It gives a float within the range 0-1

Comment: Sorry I didn't word properly my question. The event is within another event and I try to get one single random number in the inner event, giving a lot of them, instead. I reedit the question

Answer (score 2):

To get a single number in range `[0-10[`

You will need to do the following

```
Math.round(Math.random()*10)
```

`Math.random` will generate a number in range `[0,1[`.

`Math.round` will round decimals.

`*10` is used to generate a random in range `[0-10[`.

```js
$("#myId").click(() => console.log(Math.round(Math.random()*10)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='myId'>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get an `integer`, right? If so - use `Math.round` function, which will round the `floating` number into the closest integer. And since the `Math.random()` returns a floating number with range from `0` to `1` - you will always get `0` or `1` in return.

```js
$("#myId").click(function(){
    var ran = Math.round(Math.random());
    console.log(ran);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='myId'>click</button>
```

Comment: It Gives 0 or 1

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp Yeah, so what? OP didn't precise from what range he wants a random number.